# Private and Public Data in S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-s3

I'm looking to redo our S3 buckets and I need to relocate our public and private data.  My plan is to do something like this:

```
[my bucket]/public
[my bucket]/private
```

My bucket will not have public access, I will use cloudfront to deliver my public content.

My question:  Is this a good idea?

Comment: Why not two separate buckets? That seems to be the natural arrangement. Not saying your approach is problematic, it just would not have occured to me unless there is a specific reason why it needs to be a single bucket.

Comment: Yeah, that's the approach I took before.  I just wanted to see if there was a better way of doing it.  Thanks

Comment: "Better" implies that there is something that you find lacking in the current approach. What did not work so well with two buckets?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things to address here.  First of all, you can have public and private areas of your bucket through the policy.   You'll need to use something similar to this (under Bucket Properties->Permissions->Edit bucket policy):

```
{
"Version": "2008-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "*"
        },
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/public/*"
    }
]
}
```

You can certainly use CloudFront to deliver your public content, but if there's no other compelling reason (e.g. high performance worldwide, large files etc.), I wouldn't add the complexity.